# cast object to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, casting, arraylist

is it possible to cast an `Object` to e.g. `ArrayList<String>`

the code below gives an example of the problem. The Problem is in the last row

```
setDocs((ArrayList<Document>)obj);
```

where I want to cast an `Object obj` to `ArrayList<String>`

```
public void setValue(Object obj)
    {
        if(obj instanceof TFile)
            setTFile((TFile)obj);
        else
            if(obj instanceof File)
                setFile((File)obj));
            else
                if(obj instanceof Document)
                    setDoc((Document)obj);
                else
                    if(obj instanceof ArrayList)
                        setDocs((ArrayList<Document>)obj);

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: you say that, want to cast an Object `obj` to `ArrayList<String>` but in the last line u seem to cast to `ArrayList<Document>`

Comment: I wrote e.g. ArrayList<String>, but you are right, the type should be Document

Comment: Note that there will be a lot of "else if" and not else{ if(){}else{} } like it would be if you wrote this in python or something that cared about indentation and lines. I don't think the actual outcome will differ though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Java generics are not reified, i.e. their generic type is not used when casting.

So this code

```
setDocs((ArrayList<Document>)obj);
```

will be executed as

```
setDocs((ArrayList)obj);
```

As that runtime cast won't check your `ArrayList` contains `Document` objects, the compiler raises a warning.

Comment: I see ... so any suggetions how to re-write the method? Should I make the method generic as well, will then work?

Comment: As long as you have to cast you will have the issue. You can either ignore the compiler warning or directly call setDocs(ArrayList<Document>) when you have the correct type.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible due to how generics are implemented in Java.

The type information is not available at runtime, so it cannot be checked by `instanceof`.

What you can do is cast to `List` and then check each element if it is a `Document` or not.

Comment: but I know, if its from type ArrayList, then it will be ArrayList<Document>. The compiler is giving me warning on the next row, where I cast to ArrayList<Document>

Comment: Best you can do is suppress the warning. And re-think if you really need this instanceof monster. In most programs, types should be known at compile time, without the need for this dynamic inspection.

Comment: yes I know, but the code is very old and compiles with Java 1.4, so I am trying to update it to Java 1.7 and wanted to clean up some basic warning like this. Thanks any way